# Pandas groupby make two columns lists separately

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a DataFrame that has three columns. Let's call them `fruit`, `sport`, and `weather` for the sake of convenience.

What I want to do is to group the DataFrame by the `fruit` column and make the corresponding values for `sport` and `weather` into lists so that we'll have corresponding `sport` and `weather` lists for each unique `fruit`.

For example:

```
# Original DataFrame

      fruit      sport         weather
0     apple      baseball      sunny
1     banana     swimming      cloudy
2     apple      basketball    windy
3     orange     football      sunny
4     banana     hockey        windy


# Desired DataFrame
      fruit      sport                       weather
0     apple      [baseball, basketball]      [sunny, windy]
1     banana     [swimming, hockey]          [cloudy, windy]
2     orange     [football]                  [sunny]
```

Grouping one of the column values into a list is relatively straightforward, but I'm a bit stuck as to how to do that with two. How might I go about that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `groupby` and aggregate witht the `list` constructor:

```
df.groupby('fruit', as_index=False).agg(list)

    fruit                   sport          weather
0   apple  [baseball, basketball]   [sunny, windy]
1  banana      [swimming, hockey]  [cloudy, windy]
2  orange              [football]          [sunny]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table):

```
df.pivot_table(index='fruit', aggfunc=list).reset_index()
```